# Monitoring sub-task for grunt-contrib-watch

Tags: javascript, build, coffeescript, gruntjs

I have the following Gruntfile.coffee. I am monitoring the watch task as shown below to see file changes and then compile the changed file to coffee-script.

```
# Watch task
watch:
 coffee:
  files: ['client/**/*.coffee','server/**/*/.coffee']
  options:
   nospawn: true
   livereload: true

# Watch changed files
grunt.event.on 'watch', (action, filepath) ->
 cwd = 'client/'
 filepath = filepath.replace(cwd,'')
 grunt.config.set('coffee',
  changed:
   expand: true
   cwd: cwd
   src: filepath
   dest: 'client-dist/'
   ext: '.js'
 )
 grunt.task.run('coffee:changed')
```

However, I would like to add another watch task to copy files over that are not coffee files. How would I monitor these changes?

I thought of doing

```
# Watch copy task
grunt.event.on 'watch:copy', (action,filepath) -> ...
# Watch coffee task
grunt.event.on 'watch:coffee', (action,filepath) -> ...
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution - gets the job done but isn't pretty. I welcome better answers

Basically, I match the path of the incoming file
if its .coffee run a coffee compile task
if its .*** run a copy task

```
# Watch changed files
grunt.event.on 'watch', (action, filepath) ->

 # Determine server or client folder
 path = if filepath.indexOf('client') isnt -1 then 'client' else 'server'
 cwd = "#{path}/"
 filepath = filepath.replace(cwd,'')        

 # Minimatch for coffee files
 if minimatch filepath, '**/*.coffee'
  # Compile changed file
  grunt.config.set('coffee',
   changed:
    expand: true
    cwd: cwd
    src: filepath
    dest: "#{path}-dist/"
    ext: '.js'
  )
  grunt.task.run('coffee:changed')  

 # Minimatch for all others
 if minimatch filepath, '**/*.!(coffee)'
  # Copy changed file
  grunt.config.set('copy',
   changed:
    files: [
     expand: true
     cwd: cwd
     src: filepath
     dest: "#{path}-dist/"                      
    ]
  )
  grunt.task.run("copy:changed")
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the note at the bottom of the watch event example: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#using-the-watch-event

The `watch` event isn't intended on replacing the Grunt API. Use `tasks` instead:

```
watch:
  options:
    nospawn: true
    livereload: true
  coffee:
    files: ['client/**/*.coffee','server/**/*/.coffee']
    tasks: ['coffee']
  copy:
    files: ['copyfiles/*']
    tasks: ['copy']
```

Comment: I only want changed files...the watch task runs compile on all the files in those folders

Comment: Then continue to use `grunt.config.set()` in the `watch` event. Just don't use `grunt.task.run()` in the `watch` event. That is what `tasks` is for.

Comment: I would like to run the task after I filter out the files that are changed...how would I do that then?